# fullcalendar - Set current date based on timezone

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar, timezone-offset

There have been a couple of similar questions in the past, but none I've found have been fully answered so let me try again.

I'm writing this web app where users can select their particular timezone, which might be different from the one set up in their respective system.  Say my computer is set to the "America/New_York" timezone.  If I (for whatever reason) set up my timezone configuration to "Asia/Tokyo" within the web app, I would like to:

1. have the current month aligned with the configured timezone ("Asia/Tokyo") and
2. have the highlighted current date also set to the "Asia/Tokyo" timezone.

I've tried many different configurations without any luck...

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: "month",
    timezone: "Asia/Tokyo",
    ignoreTimezone: false,
    defaultDate: moment("2019-03-10"),
    header: {...
```

In this case, I'm hard coding the defaultDate for tomorrow ("2019-03-10") to see if the current date highlight changes to no avail.

Is there a way to accomplish these two issues?

**Update:**

Okay, the answer to question (2) I found to be the parameter `now`. In this case, things would look like...

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ defaultView: "month", now: moment().tz("Asia/Tokyo"), ...
```

As explained above, if say, my laptop is said to be configured with the "America/New_York" timezone, but I'm actually in Japan and my web app config reflects that, it won't matter. fullCalendar will now show the correct day for Today.

Still, the question remaining is (1): How to make the (monthly) calendar days be in sync with a given timezone? Thanks!

Comment: "How to make the (monthly) calendar days be in sync with a given timezone?" ...can you be clearer about precisely what you mean by this? In what what does the dislpay of a whole day need to sync with a specific timezone?

Comment: Hi ADyson!  Thanks for your response!  What I'm saying is that by default fullCalendar takes on the local system clock timezone when identifying the current (now) date with a (default) yellow background.  As I understand it, the same is true for the beginning and end of the month.  Thus, as described before, if the timezone my webapp is operating under is different from the local system clock timezone, I would like the beginning and end of the month to be in sync with my app's timezone and not with the local one.  How do I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: So you mean for instance if the local time is 11pm on the 31st March but the timezone you've selected is 4am on 1st April then the calendar should initialise showing April instead of March? Is that what you mean by "in sync"? (It's always better to give an exact example than use a phrase that could have more than one meaning. Then we know exactly what behaviour we're trying to implement.)

Comment: Thanks again for your response!  Great point and that's exactly what I meant by "in sync!"  That is to be _in sync_ with the _web app's timezone_ and NOT with the local system timezone. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I forgot to ask you...you've used the `ignoreTimezone` setting above...but that setting only exists in version 1 of fullCalendar. Are you still using such an old version? If so then the `timezone` setting will never work because it doesn't exist (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1#toc). Either way I would strongly advise you to upgrade to a supported version (v3 is current now, but v4 will be released very soon) before you carry on.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your replies!  No, I'm using the latest (v3). From what I can tell, I think this may have done it.  Cheers!